# Can't open console in Oblivion

Tags: pc, the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I have run into a problem that many people run into on Oblivion -- opening the console. I looked up what is wrong, found out I needed to make sure `bAllowConsole` is set to 1, and did that. However, now I've run into a secondary problem that I can't seem to find anywhere else. When I try to save the file, it won't let me, saying access is denied. What is wrong and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to overwrite files in system folders **you need to use a program with administrator rights**. By default when you open a text file notepad doesn't start in admin mode.

#### To start Notepad with Admin rights in windows 7:

- Type notepad into the search bar of the start menu
- Right click on the notepad.exe
- Select the Run as Administrator menu

[image: screenshot]

After this use **File** / **Open** to open the config file.